# How to dynamically add items to jinja variable in Flask?

Tags: python, list, variables, flask, jinja2

I'm building a website using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) with its [jinja2 templating engine](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/) and I'm dynamically building the menu ([as described here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/tricks/#highlighting-active-menu-items)):

```
{%
    set navigation_bar = [
        ('/', 'index', 'Home'),
        ('/aboutus/', 'aboutus', 'About Us'),
        ('/faq/', 'faq', 'FAQ')
    ]
%}

{% set active_page = active_page|default('index') -%}

<ul>
{% for href, id, title in navigation_bar %}
    <li{% if id == active_page %} class="active"{% endif %}>
        <a href="{{ href|e }}">{{ title|e }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Now if a user is logged in I want to show some additional things. So at runtime I want to add items to the navigation_bar variable. I tried something like this:

```
{% if g.user.is_authenticated() %}
    {% navigation_bar.append(('/someotherpage', 'someotherpage', 'SomeOtherPage')) -%}
{% endif %}
```

But unfortunately this results in the following error: `TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'navigation_bar'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endblock'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'block'.`

So: does anybody know how I can add additional items to a jinja2 variable at runtime? All tips are welcome!

[bonus question]
I was also wondering, what does the `-` do at the end of `{% set active_page = active_page|default('index') -%}`?

Comment: In what way does your code not work?

Comment: @APerson - Excuse me for leaving the error out. I added it to the question. It's a TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'navigation_bar'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endblock'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'block'.

Comment: `{% navigation_bar.append(('/someotherpage', 'someotherpage', 'SomeOtherPage')) -%}` here navigation_bar is a `list` not a `block`.IMO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error occurs because Jinja can't identify block. Each Jinja block should start from block name. `do` block from [do extension](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/extensions/#expression-statement) meets your needs. To use it you should add
do extension to jinja extensions. You can do this like so:

```
app.jinja_env.add_extension('jinja2.ext.do')
```

And then you can use do extension. Your example should looks like this:

```
{% if g.user.is_authenticated() %}
    {% do navigation_bar.append(('/someotherpage', 'someotherpage', 'SomeOtherPage')) %}
{% endif %}
```

[Here's](https://gist.github.com/bacher09/c07e505a028deda29327) another simple example.

You will find answer to your *bonus question* [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#whitespace-control). In short `-` removes whitespaces from start or end of block (this depends on where it is located).

Answer (score 0):

To complete the [answer of Slava Bacherikov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25948101/15794285), if you don't have the Jinja "do extension", you can use the tag `set`:

```
{% if g.user.is_authenticated() %}
    {# use a dummy variable name, we juste need the side-effect of method call #}
    {% set _z = navigation_bar.append(('/someotherpage', 'someotherpage', 'SomeOtherPage')) %}
{% endif %}
```